# Batman Arkham Asylum GOTY .NET Framework error

Tags: technical-issues, batman-arkham-asylum

So I just installed Batman Arkham Asylum and I got this error at starting it:

[image]

When I click Quit, It will just stop launching.

When I click Continue, It will go to a small Batman window with 6 options which I cant see because it's pitch black. When I choose one of the options I get this:

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: [this steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1189622) has several possible solutions for the problem. I'd suggest starting with [running this tool from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List of possible fixes starting from the simplest.Based on positive feedback from steam forums:

1. Simply running the game .exe directly from the `Steam\SteamApps\common\batman` folder instead from steam application.
2. Running BmLauncher.exe in `Steam\SteamApps\common\batman\ folder in windows 7 compatibility mode.
3. As TZHX mentioned downloading and installing this [direct x runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)
4. Running following installers from `Steam\SteamApps\common\batman\redist\` folder
   `DXSETUP.exe`**,** `vcredist_x86.exe` **,** `PhysX_9.08.14_9.09.0814_SystemSoftware.exe`

   - (Removing other versions of Direct X and PhysX might be necessary,best done before      installing those from batman folder,problem is that if you uninstall newer version of PhysX or DirectX some newer games could stop working until you reinstall the new 
     versions).

     ---
5. Remove all installations of .NET framework (through the Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features,or even better some software removal tool) and install [.NET framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718).Some people say that you will have to reinstall the game itself,but It seems unnecessary to me.

   - If you use windows 7 or newer with required updates you can look in `Start > Control Panel > Add remove windows features` where you can select .NET framework version you want without having to download and install.

     ---

Comment: It worked for me after uninstalling the .net framework and installing the PhysX_9.08.14_9.09.0814_SystemSoftware.exe from NVidia site.
Mine is AMD system but it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to reinstall .net framework and make sure you get the latest version. If that doesn't work, I am not sure. But that is the first thing I would try, in case there were errors during installation.

Answer (score 0):

My Advise is that   download nvidia physx      http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=104790&t=0&i=1
worked for me :)